# What's the difference between Compaq Visual Fortran and GNU Fortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77, intel-fortran

Under Linux, I used gfortran and failed to compile some Fortran 77 codes which are developed on Compaq Visual Fortran 6.5 (CVF) under Windows. Some errors are related to different keywords change, e.g. `TYPE` in CVF and `PRINT` in gfortran.

Are there detail comparison between CVF and gfortran?

Answer (score 3):

From memory, the documentation for CVF made it clear where syntax that was accepted by the compiler was an extension to the standard.  If you program uses such an extension then there's a reasonable chance that a different compiler will reject them.

The TYPE statement is such an extension - it is not in Fortran 77.

Answer (score 3):

If you look for a compiler compatible with CVF use Intel Fortran. It is its direct descendant. This site can help you

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/migrating-from-compaq-visual-fortran

But I would strongly recommend to get rid of the nonstandard extensions.